# read command line parameter flask

Tags: python, flask

To run my flask app I use : `python fapp.py myconf.conf`

reading http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/

it states :

```
$ export FLASK_APP=fapp.py
$ flask run
```

But it does not signify how to pass the command line parameter `myconf.conf` as part of startup. How to pass parameter `myconf.conf` as part of flask startup ? so can be read using :

```
 sys.argv[1]
```

What is difference between executing flask using `flask` command versus utilising `python` , is primary difference using flask enables configuration of parameters such as port number ?

Comment: why don't you just use `python`?

Comment: @Skilledfire is idiomatic to use flask instead of python ? Also i'm unable to set parameters such as port from python command line ?

Comment: you could either handle that handle that yourself, or just set it from code

Comment: I'd love to know the logic behind moving from app.run to using an environment variable and -m flask. I've found this question several times, but no clear answer.